# How to set Order BY to specific variable structure

Tags: mysql, sql

Essentially I have a column in my mySQL database that contains time intervals like:

```
8:00 am - 12:00 pm
```

The column accepts `VARCHAR` values.

How can I `ORDER BY` using this column data in `DESC` order?

I would like the query to understand `am` from `pm` and order in terms of that.

Comment: What defines the order? Length of interval or start time?

Comment: If it is not too late, change the structure of your table to have separate fields (of an appropriate data type) for interval start and end. VARCHAR alone is going to cause plenty of problems (11:00 will sort before 8:00), nevermind the fact that you have two values in one field.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Start time defines the order

Comment: @Uueerdo Nothing is too late, I am in the process of designing the db now

Comment: *" I am in the process of modeling designing the db now"* then i advice to use MySQL [time](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html) datatype instead of VARCHAR or CHAR the am/pm part/information you would need to store in a other column..

Comment: Yes, definitely split them out then. To put it diplomatically, that kind of design is at best a pain to work with, and will rarely be able to get decent performance.

Comment: "The column accepts `VARCHAR` values".  Really?  VARCHAR for time?

Comment: "I am in the process of designing the db now".  So re-design it.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to convert to times:

```
order by str_to_date(concat('2000-01-01 ', substring_index(str, ' - ', 1)), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p'),
         str_to_date(concat('2000-01-01 ', substring_index(str, ' - ', -1)), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p')
```

The date is irrelevant for the `order by`, because they are all the same.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3627ddd045efccdfd235590b3ecf458d) is a db<>fiddle showing the values produced.